# Lost Coins on Uniswap

Tags: etherscan, uniswap

I tried to swap HOKK coin for SEPA coin last night and the transaction did not go through.  My coinbase wallet still shows the HOKK coins but when I look at the transaction it says success even though components are pending.

I'm new to this and don't know why the SEPA coins didnt show up.  Please anyone if you could provide some advice it would be appreciated.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9fc1450990cf7bcbedbd776c314e60bb9e35274ef322fb83a13e45f90c933190

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe82282de0ae1998e75a27010434d880dde38306b53a487ac1c2aa839348800fe

Answer (score 0):

You just seem to have done the approve transaction, which is self-explanatory - you approved Uniswap to spend these tokens. However you didn't actually perform the sell. For that, go on the UI again and now you should be able to swap.